# Objective-C – Making several views respond to the same touch event?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, events

As you all know in Cocoa-touch the GUI is made up of several `UIView`s. Now in my view I have an `UIImageView` (containing an image) which is aligned at x:10 y:10, then I have a `UILabel` aligned at x:30 y:10 and then finally another `UILabel` aligned at x:50 y:10.

Now I would want all these `UIView`s to respond to the same touch event. What would be the easiest way to accomplish this? Would it be to create an `UIView` that will align from x:10 y:10 and cover all the views and then place this view on top of these views (`-bringSubviewToFront`)?

Cheers,

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your variant is ok! Just create `UIView` and catch all touch events by it.

Or you can put all your subviews (image, label, label) on one subview `mergeView` of main view, disable user interaction of that views (image, label, label) and to `mergeView` add gesture recognizer or whatever you want to catch touches. With such approach it will be easier to reposition your views: just reposition `mergeView`. Don't forget to enable user interaction of `mergeView`.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the touch events on the top View and explicitly pass those touches to other views you are interested in. But makes sure the touch point interesects the other views to whom you are sending the touch events

```
  -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

UITouch * touch =    [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:topView];


if (CGRectContainsPoint(view1.frame, point)) {

    [view1 touchesBegan:[NSSet setWithObject:touch] withEvent:nil];
}

if (CGRectContainsPoint(view2.frame, point)) {

    [view2 touchesBegan:[NSSet setWithObject:touch] withEvent:nil];
}

}
```